# Is it possible for an atmosphere to have gasoline mixed in it?

Tags: planets, atmosphere, fire

Is there such a thing as gasoline vapors, or some kind of gas that can be given off by gasoline? I'm trying to come up with a planet where the atmosphere is combustible and constantly catching on fire (as you can probably tell the gasoline is meant to be symbolic of something).

Comment: Gasoline fumes are unbelievably dangerous.  I once threw a half-cup of gas into a disconnected incinerator to burn off some paper trash and the seconds between doing that and lighting the match were enough to cause an explosion that nearly blew out the window behind me.  Liquid propane expands into the atmosphere at a ratio of 10,000:1 and can level whole city blocks.  But, can an *entire* atmosphere be made up of this?  Locally [marsh gas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marsh_gas) can do this, but I doubt an entire planet could be this way.  Every lightning strike would be devestating.

Comment: That is **PERFECT**. It fits the theme of the planet perfectly. Edit: if you wanna make this an answer I can select yours as being the answer I went with.

Comment: Can you smell gasoline?  Most people can, so there's obviously some vapor involved.  And as @JBH points out, in the right concentration gasoline (and many other vapors, as well as dusts like flour) can be explosive.  But a whole planetary atmosphere wouldn't work.  As soon as some local area reached an explosive/flammable concentration, something would set it off.  For an Earthly example, consider Chimaera: https://www.amusingplanet.com/2013/09/the-flaming-rocks-of-chimaera-turkey.html or certain Alaskan lakes that can be set on fire...

Comment: What actually burns in gasoline are the fumes not the liquid gasoline itself. Hydrocarbon vapor mixed with oxygen from the air = boom! The rate of vaporization depends on surface area and temperature. This is why in internal combustion engines the surface area is expanded with a manifold and for diesel and fuel oil the temperature of the fuel is increased.

Comment: @jamesqf You need oxygen for combustion, too.  So maybe on the OP's planet, hydrocarbons are everywhere but oxygen is rare -- the periodic flare-ups occur where oxygen accumulates.

Comment: @Joe: Sure, consider Titan as an example.  But it's just our parochialism that considers "burning" to be some fuel reacting with plentiful oxygen.  Titanians would consider oxygen to be the fuel, reacting with the plentiful hydrocarbons in the atmosphere.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A planetary atmosphere can be either globally oxidant (i.e. oxygen rich) or reductive (i.e. hydrocarbon based), but not both, as it would imply a mass combustion reaction which would consume one of the two components.

This is what happened on Earth during the [great oxygenation event](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Oxygenation_Event), when oxygen released by the first plants oxidated all available minerals.

To answer your question, you can have hydrocarbon atmosphere, with methane, ethane and other hydrocarbons with longer chains. But you cannot have constant catching fire on a global scale. If you have local releases of oxidant gas, it can happen.

Answer (score 4):

**You could do it with [pentane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentane).**

Imagine an green and earthlike world.  The weather is generally cool and wet.  Photosynthesizers leak oxygen into the air, as they are wont to do.  A nice place to build a cabin, you would think.

But there are shallow pockets of petrochemicals just under the surface.  They have floated up through the crust over time from huge abiogenic deep stores and the less volatile ones accumulate in the cool surface.  The boiling point of pentane is 35C or 97F.  Every now and then the planet has a really hot summer and then up comes the pentane, boiling off and into the atmosphere.  Once enough accumulates in the atmosphere - boom.  Then when the pentane fires get things hot enough, its friends hexane septane and octane come out to join the party too.  Everything burns.

It ends when there is no oxygen left in the air to support combustion.  Things cool off and the residual alkanes condense and move back to their subsurface lairs.

The photosynthesizers laugh merrily at all this.  Swinging the planet back and forth from oxic to anoxic via fire is great for them.  Like the grasses of a prairie, they are fire adapted.  Fire-adapted grasses live through fires via their deep roots, and then emerge to an environment burnt free of plant competitors and insects.  So too the photosynthesizers of your world - their fireproof spores sprout to an oxygen free world depleted of air breathing life and replete with delicious CO2.  Then just as the anaerobes think they will get back their planet, here comes the O2 again.